# List sections empty after adding .id()

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a section for each element in array. I need to use ScrollViewReader so I need to add `.id()` to each row. However, when I add id, list rows become empty. It works fine without id modifier. See the image below:

[image: screenshot showing empty list sections]

Here's the sample project I have made that demonstrates this problem:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Interval: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var index: Int
    var name : String {
        "Interval \(index)"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var intervals: [Interval] = (1...9).map { index in Interval(index: index) }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(intervals, id: \.id) { interval in
                Section {
                    Text(interval.name)
                        //.id(interval.id) // try removing this comment
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Some debugging that I have done:

Having only 1 section works, but I need one section for every element.

```swift
Section {
    ForEach(intervals, id: \.id) { interval in
        Text(interval.name)
            .id(interval.id)
    }
}
```

Adding each section manually also works, but this can't be done as I have lots of section in my actual project.

```swift
Section {
    Text(intervals[0].name)
        .id(intervals[0].id)
}
Section {
    Text(intervals[1].name)
        .id(intervals[1].id)
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: do you need Section only for styling (as it has no header or footer?   If you provide even an empty header it works fine: `Section("")` ...

Comment: @ChrisR Yes, I just want Section for styling. You are right, `Section("")` also works, but that adds empty string as the header, which adds extra space above the section for header resulting in more space between 2 sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following using a `VStack` works for me (on real devices):

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(intervals) { interval in
            Section {
                VStack { // <-- here
                    Text(interval.name).id(interval.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although this did work perfectly in the sample project I made, in my real project it fixed the empty cells but broke the ScrollViewReader's scrollTo method. It wasn't scrolling to the desired row. I have come with a weird fix that works fine without adding any extra VStack. I don't know how and why that fix works. But I will add a separate answer with that fix to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: I (we) can only answer the question you ask with the code you provide. I cannot second guess what other code you are using and for what purpose. At least you got your code "moving" again.

Comment: I get it. I tried to replicate the exact code of my real project in the sample code I provided. For sone reason, your solution fixed the sample code but didn’t fix my real project’s problem completely. I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Although @dudette's answer solved the empty cells issue in my real project, scrolling to desired cell/row wasn't working when using ScrollViewReader's scrollTo method.

I have come up with a weird fix that works for me. It is weird because I don't know how and why it works, but it works. If anyone can explain why it works, I'll be very thankful.

The solution is, I created a new ViewModifier named EmbedInSection that just embeds the content in Section.

```swift
struct EmbedInSection: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Section {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

And I used it like:

```swift
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(intervals) { interval in
            Text(interval.name)
                .id(interval.id)
                .modifier(EmbedInSection())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept @dudette 's answer as it answered the question asked. If you ask a wrong question, you get an answer that doesn't help, but when people put effort in like this, you need to acknowledge it. Otherwise, you may not get as much help in the future.